# Returning all Laravel eloquent models tagged with a specific set of tags

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

I've got an Eloquent model `Post` with a `belongsToMany(Tag::class)` relationship. Now in the situation where I want to return or get all posts with a given set of tags, what's the most efficient Laravel-esq way of performing such a query?

For example; get all posts that have the tag `bbq`, or all posts that have the tags `bbq` AND `beef`.

I'd like to simply pass an array of tags in which can be of any count, if possible. I have tried the following and a number of different combinations with no luck, granted my SQL kung-fu isn't the greatest.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('tag_types.name', ['bbq', 'beef']);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found a solution. In this case it requires knowing the ID's of the tags in question, which is easy enough to query for. In this case I store the tag ID's in an array called `$tag_ids` and use the following Eloquent query (`tag_types` being the pivot table):

```
$posts = Post::join('tag_types', function ($join) use ($tag_ids) {
    $join
        ->on('posts.id', '=', 'tag_types.post_id')
        ->whereIn('tag_types.tag_id', $tag_ids);
})
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->havingRaw('count(distinct tag_types.tag_id) = ' . count($tag_ids))
    ->lists('post_id');
```

`$posts` now contains the ID's of all the posts that contain every tag ID listed in `$tag_ids`.

Hope this helps anyone facing a similar dilemma.